# count the occurrence of categorical variables in R

Tags: r, count, find-occurrences

I have a data frame which consists of three categorical variables, and I want to find the frequency of each combination and sort the result by the frequency in descending order as follow:

my data:

```
   A LEVEL1 PASS
   A LEVEL1 FAIL
   B LEVEL2 PASS
   A LEVEL1 PASS
   B LEVEL2 PASS
   A LEVEL1 PASS
```

the result should be as follow :

```
   A LEVEL1 PASS 3
   B LEVEL2 PASS 2
   A LEVEL1 FAIL 1
```

I use plyr library,

```
  myfreq<-count(myresult,vars = NULL, wt_var = NULL) 
  myfreq<-myfreq[order-myfreq$freq,]
```

In the beginning, it works, but then it just gives me this error:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :
> Column `vars` is unknown

the other libraries I used are `rJava` and `dplyr`

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `dplyr`, which is contained in the `tidyverse` package.

I don't know what's the name of the columns in your dataframe, so I named them `col1`, `col2` and `col3` in the following example.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~ col1, ~col2, ~col3,
  "A", "LEVEL1", "PASS",
  "A", "LEVEL1", "FAIL",
  "A", "LEVEL1", "PASS",
  "B", "LEVEL2", "PASS",
  "A", "LEVEL1", "PASS")

# here is where the magic happens
df %>% count(col1, col2, col3, sort = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use group_by in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)


x <- data.frame(letter = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), level = c("LEVEL 1", "LEVEL 1", "LEVEL 2", "LEVEL 1", "LEVEL 2", "LEVEL 1"), text = c("PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS"))

df <- x %>%
     group_by_all() %>%
     count()
```

or you can do:

```
df <- x %>%
     group_by(letter, level, text) %>%
     count()
```

output:

```
> df <- x %>% group_by_all() %>% count()
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   x, y, z [3]
       x       y      z     n
  <fctr>  <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1      A LEVEL 1   FAIL     1
2      A LEVEL 1   PASS     3
3      B LEVEL 2   PASS     2
```

Comment: why would you use `group_by` before `count`?

Comment: I suppose in the event there are other columns in the df. But I guess you're right, count is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `table` function.

```
ex <- data.frame("letter" = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A"),
                 "level" = c("LEVEL1", "LEVEL1", "LEVEL2", "LEVEL1", "LEVEL2", "LEVEL1"),
                 "test" = c("PASS", "FAIL", rep("PASS", 4)))


ex

res <- data.frame(table(ex$level, ex$test))
colnames(res) <- c("level", "test", "freq")
```

You can later merge the result data.frame with the original one.

Comment: thank you all, am just wondering is there conflict between dplyr and plyr?

Answer (score 1):

Here is tidyverse with n()

```
df <- tibble(
  id = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A"),
  level = c("LEVEL1", "LEVEL1", "LEVEL2", "LEVEL1", "LEVEL2", "LEVEL1"),
  type = factor(c("PASS", "FAIL", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS", "PASS"))
)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, level, type) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id, level [?]
     id  level   type     n
  <chr>  <chr> <fctr> <int>
1     A LEVEL1   FAIL     1
2     A LEVEL1   PASS     3
3     B LEVEL2   PASS     2
```