Count Characters in Column in csv in RStudio
My dataset is being read from a csv file that has 101,777,660 entries, 3 total columns. I am trying to count the number of times these five layers/words occur in the third column (ORIG_NAME): "Slope19_Merged_forest", "CS19_Merged_Forest", "AWY19_Merged_Forest, "TWI19_Merged_Forest", and "Frag19_Merged_Forest"
An example of the dataset looks like this in the csv file:



OVERLAP_OID
ORIG_OID
ORIG_NAME




1
1
Slope19_Merged_forest


2
4
Slope19_Merged_forest


3
5
Slope19_Merged_forest


4
6
Slope19_Merged_forest


5
7
Slope19_Merged_forest



My initial code looks like this:
overlay <- read.csv("OverlayTable4.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

I have tried:
library(dplyr)

overlay |>
  filter(ORIG_NAME %in% c("Slope19_Merged_forest",
                          "CS19_Merged_Forest",
                          "AWY19_Merged_Forest",
                          "TWI_Merged_Forest",
                          "Frag19_Merged_Forest")) |>
  count(ORIG_NAME)

But got this error code:

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
filter, lag
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
Error in UseMethod("filter") :
no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "function"

I expect the outcome to give this type of information:



Column A
Total




Slope19_Merged_forest
1,500


CS19_Merged_Forest
2,000


AWY19_Merged_Forest
3,000


TWI19_Merged_Forest
1,000


Frag19_Merged_Forest
3,000



If there is any way to get the total number of each of these words that occur in the third column?

With >100M rows you're looking at quite a large file (~4Gb) and you might run into trouble with some of the approaches documented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410095/count-the-occurrence-of-categorical-variables-in-r. A potential alternative is to use "awk", e.g. you could potentially get your desired outcome using awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {a[$3]++} END{for (i in a) {print i, a[i]}}' large.csv. Hope that helps; good luck!

@jared_mamrot - using overlay <- tibble(ORIG_NAME = sample(c("Slope19_Merged_forest", "Slope19_Merged_forest", "CS19_Merged_Forest", "AWY19_Merged_Forest", "TWI19_Merged_Forest", "Frag19_Merged_Forest"), 1e8, replace = TRUE)), 100 iterations of the OPs code in microbenchmark returned a mean of  ~1.49 seconds.

I could not reproduce your error using R 4.4.1 and dplyr 1.1.4. What versions are you using? Try again in a fresh R session with no other packages loaded apart from only dplyr. You could also try using dplyr::filter instead of just filter in case the issue is a package conflict.
